# How to fix WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <taskname> though it has been deprecated as a task parameter

Tags: airflow

I keep getting the warning:

```
WARNING - schedule_interval is used for <Task(BigQueryOperator): mytask>, though it has been deprecated as a task parameter, you need to specify it as a DAG parameter instead
```

I am on google composer 1.9.0

```py
schedule_interval = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
default_args = {
    'owner': 'e',
    'catchup': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 25),
}


with models.DAG(
        dag_id=f"mydag",
        schedule_interval=schedule_interval,
        default_args=default_args,

) as dag:
    mytask
```

How do I address this warning? I thought that by explicitly specifying the schedule_interval I would avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while migrating to the latest Airflow version 1.10.10.
The message just says that you not only defined the `schedule_interval` on DAG level (like you did in your code snippet), but also on task level. In your example in the BigQueryOperator task. But defining `schedule_interval` for a task is deprecated. The same like e.g. `retry_delay_in_hours`.

To prevent this warning you just have to remove this attribute from all of your tasks.
The schedule interval from the DAG is automatically applied to the task(s). See [docs for more information](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator.schedule_interval)

Cheers
Michael

Comment: How do you remove the attribute from the task?